# How to get a specific class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want a function to return class that start with category

```
<article id="post-60425" class="post-60425 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-book-summary  series-economic-and-bourse-books has-thumbnail">
```

thanks

It has no specific index
thanks

Comment: jqObj.removeClass - search for it in the API. show the jqObj is found is “on you”.

Comment: title and content are unrelated?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getCategories(article) {
  return $(article).attr('class').split(' ').filter(function(c) {
    return c.startsWith('category')
  });
}

// One article by id
console.log(getCategories(document.getElementById('post-90988')));

// All articles
// $('article').each(function(index, item) { console.log(getCategories(item))});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-60425" class="post-60425 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-book-summary has-thumbnail"></article>
<article id="post-90988" class="post-90988 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-book-summary  category-math-books has-thumbnail"></article>
```

Comment: @user4876127, Sure, try now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeClassByPrefix(el, prefix) {
  const classes = el[0].className.split(/\s+/);
  classes.forEach((e) => {
    if(e.indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
      return e;
    }
  });
}

removeClassByPrefix($('article'), 'category-');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-60425" class="post-60425 post type-post category-book-summary has-thumbnail">some article</article>
```

Comment: I want a function to return classes that start with category
can you please help me

Comment: I see. I changed the code, let me know if it works for you

Comment: I don't want to remove this class, I want to return it. sorry my english is not good. I may ask a wrong question.

Comment: I changed it again. Should do what you want now

Answer (score 0):

You no need jQuery, try :

```js
const article = document.querySelector('article')
const categoryClass = [...article.classList].find(cls => cls.startsWith('category-'))
```